# cannot be resolved or is not a field findViewById

Tags: android

I cant find whats wrong with my code I am getting  cannot be resolved or is not a field on findViewById.

the problems lines are:

```
       playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
         buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
```

my xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ProgressBar>
<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/buttonPlay" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/buttonStopPlay" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

my code is:

```
 public class radioActivite extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.radio_xml);




    initializeUIElements();

    initializeMediaPlayer();
}

private void initializeUIElements() {

       playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    playSeekBar.setMax(100);
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
```

tried to clean the code but didn't help me.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you update the question with the stacktrace you are getting from LogCat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing your R.java so that it is regenerated. This is often Eclipse that does not see your changes in your res/ directory.
Another reason your R.java is not regenerated is you may have a problem in one of your resources (layout, styles, etc.)

Comment: I removed the R.java and it was created again.

Comment: strangely I just tried to debug the app and the errors go away.

Comment: ahaha yeah that's what he was saying

Answer (score 5):

Try to remove the keyword `android` word which will be added before `R` when you are accesing XML attributes.

```
import android.R;
...
setContentView(android.R.id.textView);
....
findViewById(android.R.id.Button2);
```

E.g.

```
import android.R.id.Button1;
```

Remove android in the above and place your package directory path..

Answer (score 4):

Check your imports, probably the wrong R file is imported. There should be the

```
import <your-project-package-name>.R;
```

line instead of

```
import android.R;
```

To quickly organize imports in Eclipse use `Ctrl+Shift+O` combination. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Vitaly Menchikovsky, Where can I check it? You should check your xml files for any errors, open the Eclipse's Problems view to see what's going wrong in your project.

Answer (score 1):

1. remove import android.R;
2. clean the project
3. then build the project again

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes in eclipse, cleaning the Project has helped me always. It's under Project->clean.

Answer (score 0):

strangely I just tried to debug the app and the errors go away.

Comment: it probably triggered a clean, or regenerate R function when you went to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

remove import android.R;

clean the project.

then build the project again.